# Apache 2.2.16: client denied by server configuration

Tags: wordpress, apache

I have problem with my server configuration. I use Apache 2.216, PHP 5.3.3 and wordpress 3.4.2 with Shopperpress. Time to time I receive error  "client denied by server configuration: path/to/file" in apache log file. It is path to _tbs.php file, but it is not problem in rights of file, because this file is called 12 times on page for getting thumbs of photos and there is error only several times. I think that it has no connection to concrete photo, because once this photo is displayed corectly and next time same photo produce error.

Do you have any idea what can be reason?
Thank you for all advices.
Viktor

Answer (score 0):

I think thats a problem by the configuration of **MaxClients** or **MaxRequestsPerChild**.

Try to restore the default configuration and try it again. If that not works, reinstall Apache and purge the old configuration.

You have given very little information. It is not clear under what conditions do you work (OS, installed modules, Log entrys,...).

WordPress 3.4.2 is very old and safety-relevant. Please update WordPress and your WP-Plugins.

Answer (score 0):

Go to you VHOST-file and replace:

```
Deny from all
Allow from 127.0.0.0/255.0.0.0
```

with:

```
Require all granted
```

This cause for old Config-Files and newer Apache-Version. Since Apache 2.4.3 a new security feature is added.